Would it be possible to build a device or structure that could absorb the impact of an asteroid?
This is probably a stupid question but as the title says would this be possible. I'm imagining some kind of large structure which absorbs the impact rather than deflects it and then, a step further even, potentially stores the energy it creates or redirects it for our use
more specifically huge asteroids that have potential to wipe us out. and not even necessarily with current technology but just theoretically in the future

Depends how big the asteroid is. The Earth, overall, has absorbed quite a few asteroids of many sizes.

OSIRIS-REx survived impact with an asteroid. But, maybe that's not exactly what you meant.

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. It doesn't seem to be among the usual methods proposed to protect against asteroids.

Humans have survived being hit by asteroids before, so the strict answer to the question is "yes".
However for the kind of "huge asteroids" that can wipe out human life, this is not realistically possible. These asteroids have masses of upwards $10^{15}$ kg and will be moving at several kilometers per second, which is way too large and too fast to stop. For comparison a passenger jet might be $500,000$kg and move at $300$m/s, both many of orders of magnitude less than an asteroid.
